# Cisco ASA 5525-X Input Current

Tags: cisco-asa

In switches, like Cisco Catalyst 2960X-24TS-L, datasheet mention input power:
100 to 240 VAC, 1A to 0.5A. 
So, I assume input current = 1A@100VAC and 0.5A@240VAC

or Cisco Catalyst 3850 + Power Supply PWR-C1-350WAC: 100-240VAC, 4-2A. 
So, I assume input current = 4A@100VAC and 2A@240VAC

But in Cisco ASA 5525-X datasheet:
AC range line voltage : 100 to 240 VAC, AC current : 4.85A

I am expecting that datasheet current (4.85A) is at 100 VAC
and because we use 220 VAC, it should be 2 or 2.5A.

I am calculating input current to size the UPS requirement and considering 4.85A is too high.

is my expectation, for 2A, correct ? do you know a reference from manual or datasheet ?

Comment: If you look at https://community.cisco.com/t5/firewalls/power-consumption-of-cisco-asa-5525-x/td-p/3009862 you will see someone else asking this exact question and the answer probably (2.5A at 220V).

Comment: Yes, he said the same but with no reference.

Comment: True.  Can you not just plug it in and see what the UPS reports that port at?

Comment: I didn't purchase it yet .. I can`t purchase until I get approval on these design calculations